# Net Core 3.0: multiple checkboxes with integer variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, checkbox

In my web app I have a self referencing `many to many relationship` of plants. The M2M relationships are good neighbours and bad neighbours. I want to be able to have a form where a user can check off the both types of neighbours and then save the form.

What I have so far:
For brevity, I will only show code to Good neighbours relation, the bad neighbours is the same.

Models

```
public class Plant
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public virtual ICollection<GoodPlants> GoodNeighbours { get; set; }
}

public class GoodPlants
{
   public int PlantId { get; set; }
   public int GoodNeighbourId { get; set; }

   public virtual Plant Plant { get; set; }
   public virtual Plant GoodNeighbour {get; set;}
}
```

My viewmodel EditViewModel:

```
public class EditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public ICollection<PlantIsSelectedViewModel> AllPlants { get; set; }
}
```

And the model PlantIsSelected

```
public class PlantIsSelectedViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isGoodNeighbour { get; set; }
    public bool isBadNeighbour { get; set; }
}
```

I have an Edit method to display the edited plant and all the other plants:

```
var plant = await _context.Plants.FindAsync(id);
ICollection<Plant> plants = _context.Plants.ToList();
ICollection<GoodPlants> goodNeighbours = await _context.GoodNeighbours
    .Where(g => g.PlantId == id)
    .Include(g => g.GoodNeighbour)
    .ToListAsync();

GoodPlants ownGoodPlant = goodNeighbours.FirstOrDefault(i => i.GoodNeighbour.Id == plant.Id);
Plant ownPlant = plants.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == plant.Id);
goodNeighbours.Remove(ownGoodPlant);
plants.Remove(ownPlant);

//populate the viewmodel
EditViewModel plantModel = new EditViewModel();
plantModel.Id = plant.Id;
plantModel.Name = plant.Name;
plantModel.AllPlants = _mapper.Map<ICollection<PlantIsSelectedViewModel>>(Plants);

foreach (var element in plantModel.AllPlants)
{
   if (goodNeighbours.Any(g => g.GoodNeighbour.Id == element.id))
   {
       element.isGoodNeighbour = true;
   }
   else if (badNeighbours.Any(g => g.BadNeighbour.Id == element.id))
   {
       element.isBadNeighbour = true;
   }
}
```

This desperately needs refactoring, but thats not the main issue here.

In my view I contrast the elements of `AllPlants` collection if it appears on either of the `neighbours` collections and have the `checkbox` set to checked or not:

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AllPlants)
    {
       <tr>
          @if (item.isGoodNeighbour)
          {
             <td>
                @Html.Label(item.name)
             </td>
             <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="@Model.AllPlants"
                      value="@item.id"   
                      @(Html.Raw("checked=\"checked\"")) 
                 />
             </td>
             <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="@Model.AllPlants"
                     value="@item.id" />
             </td>
           }
           // else statements below for badneighbours and cases without any relation.
           // ...
        </tr>
    }
```

I want to know how I can keep track of all the selected items (and unselected), get them in my `editViewModel` and send them back to my `[HttpPost] Edit method`. My current [HttpPost] method receives the same viewmodel, but the AllPlants property is empty.
How do I receive the correct data back?

Thanks in advance, I'm pretty stuck!

Comment: Is the problem that you can't get the selected value in your Edit mehod? How is your edit method, and which model do you use to receive the data submitted by form?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My current viewmodel is empty in my Post method. See the changed code above.

Comment: You can press f12 to check the data in your request, and you will find the submitted checkbox name is a complex object type. If you want to bind the value to your viewmodel, you should keep the names of the passed and received parameters the same. I think you can define a variable i in the razor page, 
 which increases in the foreach loop, and change the checkbox name as <input type="checkbox" name="AllPlants[@i].id" />. Besides, I don't understand why you have two checkboxes for a same field.